# how to subscribe long polling queue in aws ?? i didn't get the button "subscribe queue to sns notification " in queue action

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

how to subscribe long polling queue in aws ?? i didn't get the button "subscribe queue to  sns notification " in queue action!!

i followed the steps in documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-long-polling-for-queue.html

[this was the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoZJC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Long polling is how you **use** a query not what the query is. As seen on the screenshot your query is FIFO and the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-subscribe-queue-sns-topic.html) says:

> Amazon SNS isn't currently compatible with FIFO queues.